# React Native onRegister event not working (iOS)

Tags: react-native, push-notification

Having a time with notifications again after upgrading to the new version of RN (again)...

This function never gets called. It doesn't matter if I have *requestPermissions:true* or not

```
  PushNotification.configure({
    onRegister: (tokenResponse) => {
      console.log("AppNotifications::onRegister", tokenResponse);
    }
    ...
```

if *requestPermissions:false*, I call after logging in:

```
PushNotification.requestPermissions( (response) => {
  console.log('NotificatoinsState::requestPermissions', response);
});
```

...which also does absolutely nothing.

Couple things that always get asked in all these threads:

- Xcode capabiltity for Push Notifications is added
- Developer.apple.com has the right certs and they are not expired
- I'm running this on a device, not the simulator...
- I've tried to have the PushNotification.config in both a state as well as completely outside of the React component lifecycle, both are the exact same

Not sure what configuration I'm missing here, but any help would be super.

Opened this ticket as well in case this gets figured out in one spot or the other:
https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1052

On a deadline, so I'll keep trying stuff and if I find the answer, I'll put it here too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I forgot to update the AppDelegate.m file...

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios

Works fine now.

Comment: I have the same issue, but i testing on emulator, in your case, work fine?

Comment: @LcsGrz push notifications don't work on ios simulator, please testing on iPhone.